# Python Video Processing

Tags: python, multithreading, video-processing

I have written a code which plays a video in two different frames using two threads.The code looks fine but the cv2.imshow method does not display the videos playing. The video player opens and closes immediately. 
Help required in resolving the issue.

```
import threading 
import cv2  
def print_cube(num): 
    """ 
    function to print cube of given num 
    """
    print("start")
    print(num)
    cv2.imshow("video1",num)
    print("end")
    cv2.destroyAllWindows() 

def print_square(num): 
    """ 
    function to print square of given num 
    """
    print("start1")
    print(num)
    cv2.imshow("video2",num)

    print("end2")  
if __name__ == "__main__": 
    # creating thread 
    cap = cv2.VideoCapture("C:\\Users\shakarna\Desktop\video.mp4")

    while(True):
        # Capture frame-by-frame
        ret, frame = cap.read()

        # Our operations on the frame come here
        gray = cv2.cvtColor(frame, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)

        t1 = threading.Thread(target=print_square, args=(frame,)) 
        t2 = threading.Thread(target=print_cube, args=(gray,)) 

        # starting thread 1 
        t1.start() 
        # starting thread 2 
        t2.start()     
        # wait until thread 1 is completely executed 
        t1.join() 
        # wait until thread 2 is completely executed 
        t2.join() 
        if cv2.waitKey(1) & 0xFF == ord('q'):
            break
cap.release()
cv2.destroyAllWindows()
```

Comment: What is the expected result? To play the videos but have them display as grayscale?

Comment: to play two  videos parllely

Comment: I haven't tested your code but the problem might be either `cv2.destroyAllWindows()` or that you're using a While loop. Try removing all `cv2.destroy...` first.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

the problem could be that your code cannot find the video. To look whether this is the problem or not place your mp4 file into the same folder as your code, than

cap = cv2.VideoCapture("C:\Users\shakarna\Desktop\video.mp4")

should be

cap = cv2.VideoCapture("video.mp4")